# Hubspot Marketing Events

Tags: hubspot, hubspot-crm, hubspot-api

I have a question regarding a Hubspot Marketing Events

1. Can make an api(http) call after or on button click for create event button? If yes! the how to to it?

hubspot-> contacts (menu) -> Contacts-> Marketing Event

Answer (score 0):

The best bet would be to reach out to Hubspot directly and ask about their promotion kit. it is in their best interest to make sure that everybody knows how to properly promote their event.

That said, you can also take a look at [oyova.com](https://www.oyova.com) to get an idea of what the final result would look like

Again, the best first step would be to reach out to Hubspot directly. They have a responsive support team from my experiences